# Where is the latest version of template?

Tags: moodle

I need to build a custom type of question for Moodle 2.8

The only place I could find a question template is at:

https://moodle.org/mod/data/view.php?d=13&rid=443&filter=1

But, when I downloaded the template, in the READ ME file:

```
'''WARNING, THIS TEMPLATE IS NOT COMPLETE YET!'''
```

So, AM I looking in the wrong place for the template? I've also noticed that 
the tempalte `Requires: Moodle 1.7 or later`, so it might be a bit old..

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a link in the old plugins directory.

There are some notes here for creating a question type in Moodle 2.x : https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Question_types

A template can be cloned from here : https://github.com/jamiepratt/moodle-qtype_TEMPLATE/

Comment: Thank you!, I will check them and see